# Establish a network between two remote systems

Tags: network, networking, remote

Is it possible to create a network between remote systems without internet?
if true; how?

Comment: Connecting two or more networks is called an internet. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11100/8499).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be some kind of connectivity between the remote systems - twisted pair, fiber, wireless radio, avian carrier, ... If that network is trusted, connect away. If it's untrusted, use encrypted tunneling - VPN.